# should I use if statement in django template, although I'm using it in models.py

Tags: python, django

Here's my code, I'll explain what problem I'm having with my code. 
I have

```
def comment_count(self):
    if self.comment_set.count() > 0:
        return self.comment_set.count()
    else:
        return "no"
```

in my models.py.
and in my template I use the above function as such

```
<a href='#' class='replies'>           
      {{comment.comment_count}} replies</a>
```

but thing is I don't want there to be any thing if comment_set.count is zero. right now, it shows no replies if there's no comment_set.count.

I can probably use django template language for this, and do something like 
`{% if comment.comment_count > 0 %}` but i don't know if this is the best way. also I'm not even sure if this is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def comment_count(self):
    return self.comment_set.count()
```

And in template

```
{% if comment.comment_count %}
<a href='#' class='replies'>{{comment.comment_count}} replies</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: thank you i don't know why I didn't think of this, I guess I thought comemnt_set.count still existed  with 0...

Answer (score -1):

Do:

```
{% if comment.comment_count > 0 %}
    <a href='#' class='replies'>{{comment.comment_count}} replies</a>
{% endif %}
```

It's okay to use logic in this case :)

Comment: Yes, but he was asking if it was okay to use DTL